# Sum the column while next value of rows is not null

Tags: mysql

I have a **MySQL** table called `agent_log` like picture 1. I want output like picture 2.

That means, `wait_sec` will be sum with next rows while a new `uniqueid` has come. When come a new uniqueid then again it will be sum with next `wait_sec` while next `uniqueid` are null.

Please see the attached images for clear the concept.

**Picture 1/My Table**

[image]

**Picture 2/Expected output**

[image]

Comment: As stated, your question cannot be answered, because the sample data lacks a column which provides for the _order_ you seem to be expecting here.  Please add a column which generates the order.

Comment: How do you know when is the next `uniqueid`? I mean do you at least have a datetime column?

Comment: This is a pretty generic comment but this seems a bit insane, maybe you should reapproach this in a way that doesn't require you to `SUM` anything?

Comment: Question updated: I have `event_time` column.

Comment: @AsadujjamanSagor After getting the result, You can process using ur scripting language eg : php to get your required result.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1

```
select max(uniqueid), sum(wait_sec)
from (
  select *, (select count(uniqueid) from agent_log a2 where a2.event_time < a1.event_time) gg
  from agent_log a1
) as a
group by gg
```

Solution 2

```
select uniqueid, wait_total
from (
  select a.*,
    if(@prev_id is null, @wait_tot := @wait_tot + a.wait_sec, @wait_tot  := a.wait_sec) AS wait_total,
    @prev_id  := a.uniqueid AS prev_id
  from ( select @prev_id  := NULL, @wait_tot := 0 ) i
  join ( select * from agent_log order by event_time ) a
)a
where uniqueid is not null
```